# @Media Not Removing Image

Tags: html, css, image, media-queries, display

I'm attempting to make the site a little mobile friendly. I have an image (splitter-vertical.jpg) between the menu/nav & main content. I'm attempting to use:

```css
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  img.splitter-off {
    display: none;
  }
}
.left-img-col {
  width: 8%;
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-img-col">
   <img class="splitter-off" src="https://tlod.net/include/img/splitter-vertical.jpg">
</div>
```

To remove the image on smaller screens.

But no matter the amount (500px, 300px, 900px) the image doesn't go away. I've also tried min-width: and couldn't get it to work. FireFox, Chrome, & Edge still display it no matter how big the browser window is. Even cleared cookies/cache and it still remains. [View Live Site Here](https://tlod.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your style.css file , you have this code :

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  img.splitter-off {
    display: none;
  }
}
img.splitter-off {
  display: block;
}
```

change this code to :

```
 img.splitter-off {
      display: block;
    }
    @media (max-width: 800px) {
      img.splitter-off {
        display: none;
      }
    }
```

You shloud use media queries after main css.

Comment: Well I was messing around with it and:
`@media (min-width:0px) and (max-width:1200px) {
  img.splitter-off {
    display: none; margin: 0 auto;
  }
}`

I also removed:
`img.splitter-off {
      display: block;
    }`
Worked, but now the main content doesn't move below the navigation like it did and just crams into the navigation. (updated files at link above).

Comment: You must add media query to `.right-col` like this : `@media (max-width: 800px) { .right-col { width:95%}}

Comment: please thumb up

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Also quickly changed it to flexbox so its also better responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Well this will work on safari but not any other browser.

The problem is that you missed out the `media-type`.

You wrote `@media (max-width: 800px)`

The CSS should be as follows:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  img.splitter-off {
    display: none;
  }
}
.left-img-col {
  width: 8%;
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Check this snippet out:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  img.splitter-off {
    display: none;
  }
}
.left-img-col {
  width: 8%;
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-img-col">
   <img class="splitter-off" src="https://tlod.net/include/img/splitter-vertical.jpg">
</div>
```

Hope I could help